# If $a,b\geq1$, then $ab \le e^{a-1}+b \ln b$

Tags: inequality

My question is how to prove that, if $a,b>1$, then $ab \le e^{a-1}+b \ln b$.

I  tried  to  apply  the mean  value  theorem  unfortunately  I  could  not  see  actually.
If  you  can  do  please  solve  it.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $a \geqslant 1$ and consider

$$f_a \colon [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R};\quad f_a(b) = e^{a-1} + b\ln b - ab.$$

You have

$$f_a'(b) = \ln b + 1 - a,$$

so $f_a$ is (strictly) decreasing until $\ln b = a-1$, or $b = e^{a-1}$, and (strictly) increasing from then on. You have the minimum

$$ f_a(e^{a-1}) = e^{a-1} + e^{a-1}\cdot (a-1) - ae^{a-1} = 0,$$

so $f_a(b) \geqslant 0$ for all $b\in [1,\infty)$.

Comment: Nice  solution  thanks  Daniel  Fischer

Comment: just curious, but where in this deduction does it use that $a,b > 1$?

Comment: ok found it.  To solve for $\ln b = a - 1$.

Comment: @breeden Actually, it works for arbitrary $a$ and $b > 0$ (or $b\geqslant 0$ if you set $0\ln 0 = 0$).